# how can i set differnt font on UIButton Dynamically?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uibutton

I want to set custom font for button title dynamically so how can i set it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
UIButton *button        = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.titleLabel.font  = [UIFont fontWithName:@"font name" size:12];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[tmp setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"American Typewriter" size:18]];
```

the font name take it from an array and keep changing the index.

So it will look like

```
[tmp setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:[fontArray objectAtIndex:desiredIndex] size:18]];
```

Comment: setFont is deprecated and it's not working.Do you have any alternative solution Please.

Comment: Yes. Use this code.
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"font name" size:12]; 
Will work for your case.. :)